# How can I add web view preferences to a swift ui web view

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview, swiftui

I've tried so many things that just aren't working out with the playinlinemedia = true such as;

```
struct WebViewY : UIViewRepresentable {
    @State var allowsInlineMediaPlayback: Bool = true

    let url = URL (string: "https://www.youtube.com?playsinline=1")
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {

            let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
            webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

        return WKWebView(frame: .zero)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let req = URLRequest(url: url!)
        uiView.load(req)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to move it into `updateUIView` method instead?

Comment: Yes I have but it still doesn’t work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant the following

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView  {

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

    return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
}
```